# Insert variable inside img src link in html

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So I'm making simple crypto Flask web.
I'm trying to display some crypto prices with their icons in live ticker

I have done almost everything but problem comes when I try to upload icons of crypto

Thats my def where I get data from api

```
def liveTicker():
    url = f'https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets?limit=15'
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    return data['data']
```

Later I pass it to my html page with render_template, and in html I make a loop to get symbol and price so I can display.

But I don't know how can I update my img src so I can pass {{ item['symbol'].lower() }} inside it replacing "btc" value with all the symbols I get from that api.

```html
>                 <div class="liveticker">
>                     <ul>
>                         {% for item in result %}
>                             <li><img src ="https://assets.coincap.io/assets/icons/btc@2x.png"></a>{{ item['symbol'] }} {{ item['priceUsd'] | float | round(2) }}</li>
>                         {% endfor %}
>                     </ul>
>                 </div>
> 
>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the contents of `data["symbol"]` (wether it contains the whole URL or only the symbol name), you can only pass the URL of `data["symbol"]` or prefix it with the domain and path:

```
<div class="liveticker">
    <ul>
        {% for item in result %}
            <li><img src ="{{ item['symbol'] }}"></a> {{ item['priceUsd'] | float | round(2) }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="liveticker">
    <ul>
        {% for item in result %}
            <li><img src ="https://assets.coincap.io/assets/icons/{{ item['symbol'] }}"></a> {{ item['priceUsd'] | float | round(2) }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I have tried this but looks like I must have made some stupid mistake before